# How to dump/write multiple json files with a different name at each iteration in the loop ? e.g. +1?

Tags: python, json, loops, file

For every json file that I create and dump in the loop, how can I make it so that it writes new files ?

**My code:** (the content of the for-loop is irrelevant,  it is just to give an overview of what I am doing).

```
with open('my_json.json') as file:
  config = json.load(file)

for pr in path_recording:
    for pj in my_list[:5]:
        config['input']['files'][0]['path'] = pr ## change the json file as desired
        config['input']['files'][1]['path'] = pj
        with open('config.json', "w") as outfile:  ## create at each loop a new json dump with new name
            json.dump(config, outfile)
```

**current output:**
1 json file called config, which is created at the last iteration of the loop.

```
config.json
```

**desired output:**
written files with a +1 in the filename representing each iteration.

```
config0.json
config1.json
config2.json
config3.json
config4.json
```

**Idea:** transform the filename into an f-string and include a counter in it starting at 0?

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 0
for pr in path_recording:
    for pj in my_list[:5]:
        config['input']['files'][0]['path'] = pr ## change the json file as desired
        config['input']['files'][1]['path'] = pj
        with open(f'config{i}.json', "w") as outfile:  ## create at each loop a new json dump with new name
            json.dump(config, outfile)
        i += 1
```

This uses f-strings which were introduced in python 3.6. If you are using an earlier version you may want to use either `'config{}.json'.format(i)`, `'config%d.json' % i` or `'config' + str(i) + '.json'`.

Comment: maybe mention this is only for Python 3 as you're using format strings?